# JPA Criteria Builder sum query, which is identical to another query returning a list, does not generate any sql and just returns 0

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, criteria-api

I have two methods, one attempts to sum the numMinutes field on an entity using the CriteriaBuilder's `sum` method, the other returns the list of entities and I manual loop through them and sum the numMinutes field.

The first method returns 0, but the second returns the correct answer.  When diagnosing this I switched on printing of SQL in my persistence.xml and the first method prints nothing.  When debugging the HQL is pretty identical as you'd expect.

The two methods are below, my question is, why is the first one so broken, and how am I supposed to do this?

Broken method attempting to sum the values on the Database layer:

```
public int getTotalTimeRecordedForContract(SupplierServiceContract contract) {
    CriteriaBuilder builder = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Integer> criteria = builder.createQuery(Integer.class);
    Root<TimeUserTransaction> root = criteria.from(TimeUserTransaction.class);

    List<Predicate> allPredicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
    allPredicates.add(
        builder.between(root.get(TimeUserTransaction_.dateRecorded), contract.getStartDate(), contract.getExpiryDate())
    );
    allPredicates.add(
        builder.equal(root.get(TimeUserTransaction_.transaction).get(TransactionPlus_.supplierService), contract.getSupplierService())
    );

    TypedQuery<Integer> query = this.getEntityManager().createQuery(
        criteria.select(builder.sum(root.get(TimeUserTransaction_.numMinutes))).where(allPredicates.toArray(new Predicate[allPredicates.size()]))
    );

    return query.getFirstResult();
}
```

Method returning the list which should be identical except it returns allt eh entities, with no attempt to aggregate and sum the numMinutes column:

```
public List<TimeUserTransaction> getTimeRecordedForContract(SupplierServiceContract contract) {
    CriteriaBuilder builder = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<TimeUserTransaction> criteria = builder.createQuery(TimeUserTransaction.class);
    Root<TimeUserTransaction> root = criteria.from(TimeUserTransaction.class);

    List<Predicate> allPredicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
    allPredicates.add(
        builder.between(root.get(TimeUserTransaction_.dateRecorded), contract.getStartDate(), contract.getExpiryDate())
    );
    allPredicates.add(
        builder.equal(root.get(TimeUserTransaction_.transaction).get(TransactionPlus_.supplierService), contract.getSupplierService())
    );

    TypedQuery<TimeUserTransaction> query = this.getEntityManager().createQuery(
        criteria.select(root).where(allPredicates.toArray(new Predicate[allPredicates.size()]))
    );

    return query.getResultList();
}
```

The JPQL appears to be, while debugging, for the first method:

```
select sum(generatedAlias0.numMinutes) from TimeUserTransaction as generatedAlias0 where ( generatedAlias0.dateRecorded between :param0 and :param1 ) and ( generatedAlias0.transaction.supplierService=:param2 )
```

and for the second:

```
select generatedAlias0 from TimeUserTransaction as generatedAlias0 where ( generatedAlias0.dateRecorded between :param0 and :param1 ) and ( generatedAlias0.transaction.supplierService=:param2 )
```

Which baffles me even more as if the first method generates HQL, why doesn't it then turn that into JPQL and run that on the database.

I'm using a hibernate implementation of the JPA connecting to a mysql database - just in case this is relevant.

Comment: maybe the sum method on Hibernate's implementation of Criteria is broken? And when you just use the equivalent JPQL directly? The JPA implementation I use (DataNucleus) overrides the toString() of the criteria query to allow me to see the JPQL it equates to ... maybe Hibernate has some such option

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the `.groupBy(root.get(TimeUserTransaction_.numMinutes))`. `GROUP BY` is required if you select multiple columns and use one column with a Aggegrate function like count, sum. Since you are selecting only sum of numMinutes you don't need to do that.

When you do that it will group all unique `numMinutes` with its sum. If som numMinutes have 0 then those also will be summed to 0 and will be grouped together. 0 will be at top because it will be ordered ascending by default and `query.getFirstResult();` will return 0.

```
public int getTotalTimeRecordedForContract(SupplierServiceContract contract) {
    CriteriaBuilder builder = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Integer> criteria = builder.createQuery(Integer.class);
    Root<TimeUserTransaction> root = criteria.from(TimeUserTransaction.class);

    List<Predicate> allPredicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
    allPredicates.add(
        builder.between(root.get(TimeUserTransaction_.dateRecorded), contract.getStartDate(), contract.getExpiryDate())
    );
    allPredicates.add(
        builder.equal(root.get(TimeUserTransaction_.transaction).get(TransactionPlus_.supplierService), contract.getSupplierService())
    );

    TypedQuery<Integer> query = this.getEntityManager().createQuery(
        criteria.select(builder.sum(root.get(TimeUserTransaction_.numMinutes))).where(allPredicates.toArray(new Predicate[allPredicates.size()]));
    );

    return query.getFirstResult();
}
```

Comment: Sorry - I left the groupBy in there from when I was trying out suggested fixes - the code fails regardless of the groupBy.  I've edited the code to reflect this now.

Thanks for the effort, but this is not the correct answer...